# gunicorn - not taking config file if executed from shell script

Tags: python, django, bash, shell, gunicorn

This is the code for my shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash  
source /path/to/active
gunicorn_django -c /path/to/conf.py -D
```

The above sh file when executed, starts gunicorn process but it is not using the config file .

But, if i execute the command directly from the command line, like

```
gunicorn_django -c path/to/conf.py -D
```

then it is using the config file .

Also, in the sh file, if i give options directly like -w 3 -error-logfile etc.. then it is taking options .

Comment: You need to give the full path to the `conf.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script, worked for me :

```
#!/bin/bash  
source /path/to/active
gunicorn_django -c $(pwd)/path/to/conffilefrom/presentworkingdirectory -D
```